# Посоветуйте как лучше деплоить Django-проекты

Tags: python, django

Нигде не могу найти какой-то цельной информации как правильно и самое главное удобно деплоить что-то на Django на боевой сервер. Все способы, которые я нашел предполагают пляски с бубном вокруг VPS на час-другой, а без опыта так и на целый день.

Неужели у ферймворка на котором так легко писать нет такого же простого способа деплоить написанное? Поделитесь как вы это делаете или киньте почитать что-нибудь по этому поводу, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/

Comment: Просто используйте любую систему автоматизации, которая все эти пляски на несколько часов выполнит автоматически. В ответе вон уже предложили Docker, лично я использую Ansible

Answer (score 0):

Как я деплоил и деплою проект

Как деплоил раньше:

1. Беру обычный виртуальный сервак, не хостинг сайтов с php, а прям чистый вирт. сервер
2. Закатываю туда свой код через git
3. pip3 install -r requirements.txt
4. запуск проекта через gunicorn (а лучше через supervisor'а)

Как сейчас деплою проектики:

1. Беру готовый карказ проекта https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template
2. Беру обычный виртуальный сервак, как с первого пункт ввыше
3. Устанавливаю докер и его приблуды на сервер
4. Закатываю туда свой код через git
5. docker-compose build
6. docket-compose run

Вуаяля готов!

Comment: Но докер для мало-мальски сложного проекта тоже нужно настраивать несколько часов :) Готового образа может не хватить для многих нетривиальных задач

Comment: Ну я использую примерно первый способ, правда с uwsgi. Но ведь это не совсем так просто, как вы описываете, там все равно хватает возьни - сокеты всякие, конфиги nginx и все в таком духе. Не то, чтобы это очень сложно, но я вот так залил 3 маленьких проекта и все равно каждый раз забываю чего куда)